# Is it possible to specify `panic = "abort"` for a specific target?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

If I specify `panic` like this, it works for all targets:

```
[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

I want to specify `panic = "abort"` only for `target=arm-linux-androideabi`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to add a [`.cargo/config`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) to your project and use it to specify the panic settings instead of Cargo.toml:

```
[target.arm-linux-androideabi]
rustflags = ["-C", "panic=abort"]
```

The two main configuration headings you will want to look at are `[target.$triple]` and `[target.'cfg(...)']`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you could try to accomplish this: add a custom panic handler, gather a stack-trace, parse the stack-trace to determine what library the panic occurred in, and then *only* abort if you detect it as having occurred within that library.

Is this hacky/brittle? Yes.

But the option is there if for some reason you want it!

Starting point:

```rust
panic::set_hook(Box::new(|info| {
    //let stacktrace = Backtrace::capture();
    let stacktrace = Backtrace::force_capture();
    println!("Got panic. @info:{}\n@stackTrace:{}", info, stacktrace);
    if guess_library_from_stacktrace(stacktrace) == "library-X" {
        std::process::abort();
    }
}));
```

Here is a GitHub comment with more details: https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/2002#issuecomment-1020443386